# Reconnect socket in disconnect event

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to reconnecct the socket after the disconnect event is fired with same socket.id here is my socket config

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var connect_clients = [] //here would be the list of socket.id of connected users
http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

So on disconnect event i want to reconnect the disconnected user with same socket.id if possible

```
socket.on('disconnect',function(){
var disconnect_id = socket.id; //i want reconnect the users here
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming that a `socket.id` will uniquely identify a _user_ instead of a _connection_. The server will [generate a new id for each connection](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/ec673d11f162801b833a516526c1e36fa38f81b6/lib/server.js#L262), and you can't override that.

Comment: ok if the same socket.id cant be reconnect i want reconnect them with new generated socket id then

Comment: The default for `socket.io-client` _is_ to reconnect automatically (documented [here](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)), the `reconnection` option).

Answer (score 6):

By default, Socket.IO does not have a **server-side** logic for reconnecting. Which means each time a client wants to connect, a new socket object is created, thus it has a new id. It's up to you to implement reconnection.

In order to do so, you will need a way to store something for this user. If you have any kind of authentication (passport for example) - using `socket.request` you will have the initial HTTP request fired before the upgrade happened. So from there, you can have all kind of cookies and data already stored.

If you don't want to store anything in cookies, the easiest thing to do is send back to client specific information about himself, on connect. Then, when user tries to reconnect, send this information again. Something like:

```
var client2socket = {};
io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    var uid = Math.random(); // some really unique id :)
    client2socket[uid] = socket;

    socket.on('authenticate', function(userID) {
        delete client2socket[uid]; // remove the "new" socket
        client2socket[userID] = socket; // replace "old" socket
    });
});
```

Keep in mind this is just a sample and you need to implement something a little bit better :) Maybe send the information as a request param, or store it another way - whatever works for you.

Comment: as in client api gives a number of options for reconect but i was not able to  use it due to poor documentation of it so could you help me out?

Comment: Uhhh, socket.io does too have logic for reconnecting so your first paragraph seems completely wrong.

Comment: My bad, wanted to say **sever-side** logic. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question again. You should either accept the answer, provide your own, or delete the question :)